# Slick-slider, align focusOnSelect on the right side on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using slick slider on an image list, and using the focusOnSelect attr.
The focusOnSelect attribute aligns the image I click on the left side of the slider.
How do I align the item clicked on the right side of the slider?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        variableWidth: true,
        draggable: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
    });
});
```